# Type specific Functions

Tags: c, code-readability

I'm not sure if this method of creating multiple definitions for a function to handle diffrent variable types has a name, but I'm wondering if there is a benifit to it. And why it woulden't be better to just define the void pointer function.

```
typedef enum{
    my_char,
    my_u8,
    my_flt
}my_type

char* foo_char(char* bar);
uint8_t* foo_u8(uint8* bar);
float* foo_f(float* bar);
void* foo(void* bar, my_type type);

char* foo_char(char* bar){
    return food(bar, my_char);    
}

uint8_t* foo_u8(uint8* bar){
    return foo(bar, my_u8);
}

float* foo_f(float* bar){
    return foo(bar, my_float);
}
void* foo(void* bar, my_type type){
    switch(type){
        case(my_char):
            //code
        case(my_u8):
            //code
        case(my_float):
            //code
        default():
}
```

Comment: _why it woulden't be better to just define the void pointer function._: Using the pointer to type versions allows the compiler to emit warnings/errors if a bad/unaligned pointer is passed.

Comment: I am inclined to think this will spill into more or less *opinions*, but I can offer you this bit: Microsof, for instance, a large number of C functions in their Windows API, with two variants each, where the function's name ends with either `A` and `W`depending on whether it's an ANSI (ASCII) variant or "wide character" variant. Has to do with text processing. Examples: [`TextOutA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-textouta) and [`TextOutW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-textoutw) procedures.

Comment: Q: if you're passing all types via void pointer to `foo`, what is `foo` doing with the object?

Comment: Is the code you posted the existing code, or what you propose changing the code to? Either way, what you have there doesn't make any sense. `foo` has no way to use the pointer it's given (because it doesn't know the type of the object to which it points).

Comment: @ikegami This was more of a question about code planning/ general curiosity. I see what you mean about  `foo` not knowing what the type is. I changed the code so that foo accepts a type variable as well, and now I think I see what this method is used.

Comment: How is that cleaner than having the code in their respective subs? It just adds a whole lot of lines that amount to absolutely nothing. This is the definition of obfuscation.

Comment: @ikegami depends on what's happening in `foo`, this is not actual code, I'm probably asking this in the area. If there was a lot of repeated code in each function, independent of the input type, it makes sense to write it once. it creates in my opinion more readable code.

Comment: Re "*depends on what's happening in `foo`*", Does it? Either way, your question stands at: "If I add all this overhead, does it make things easier to read?" And the answer to that is no.